# A better swing gui design?

Tags: java, swing, graphics, binary-tree

I am working on a project for an online class I made the mistake of taking this summer and I need to build a gui to show how the huffman code algorithm works. The algorithm part is easy, its not very complicated. However im unsure what the best way to draw the tree(forrest) at each step. It would have to start out as just n nodes (with chars in them) on the screen and then you would press a "next" button and it would pick the two lowest nodes weighted (based on character frequency) characters and make them children of a new node (with just a weight - no char) and then update the screen/panel.

I have made swing gui before, my skills are nothing special but I know my way around. However im stuck on this implementation. I have a couple hundred lines of code written right now, but it doesnt work and I think its bad anyway, so I want to "start over" and plan it out better. So Id just like some advice on the data structure to keep track of the nodes and how to draw them on the screen.

I was using an ArrayList of JPanels as nodes and trying to draw them to a null layout. Im sure this is awful and id like to know a better way. Possibly GridBagLayout?

NOTE: don't say JTree.

Comment: Your first mistake is using a null layout.

Comment: 1) is there only one culumn of `JPanels`, or more then one 2) `JPanels` are same `width & height` 3) are you placed your `JPanels` to the `JScrollPane`

Comment: @mKorbel its a BST, i dont know what else to tell you. It is possible to have 1 node or 1000 (not really ill probably limit it).

Comment: @Paul Sasik Jtree will work, however I would only do that if it came down to time to turn it in and I didnt have something else working.

Comment: @Bill: You still don't say why you don't want to use it. Can you justify this decision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good option is to just use a library for drawing trees/graphs.  I've had good success with [Visual Library](http://platform.netbeans.org/graph/) in the past.

Another possibility is [Prefuse](http://prefuse.org/)

Comment: Id like to do it with prefuse. Ive never used it before but it sounds better than drawing my own tree. Ill have to make sure its ok with the prof first. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of wrestling with the different Swing layouts you could just do custom 2D drawing. See for a simple [enter link description here](http://www.cs.bris.ac.uk/jot/graphics/drawing/lines.html)example here on how to get started.

Comment: +1 Custom drawing is very good way to go.  Here's a more complete example: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/

Comment: I suppose this is the way ill have to go.

Comment: It's a good thing to have in your toolbox/bag of tricks. 2D drawing can be very powerful when you encounter UIs that don't behave the way you want them to (or exist at all.) It's also not that difficult to do. Just make sure to keep your code clean and manageable.

Answer (score 1):

Use an image of a tree (only one instance) and an array or other data structure to contain the "data" that the algorithm uses. Think about how you can use the data to determine where the image should be painted. Use the repaint() after the algorithm runs.

[Next] --> Algorithm runs --> Update using repaint();

So you have a single frame, a single panel and a single BufferedImage object. 
The trick will come in when you have to get slightly mathematical to know at what co-ordinates a node should be painted.

The layout of your components are insignificant, as you're not adding any components to the container, just painting image data onto it.

Comment: This is the same idea but more complicated than Paul Sasik's answer.  Instead of creating a panel, drawing an image and then putting an image on the panel, you can just draw directly on the panel.  In fact, you will be using the exact same methods for drawing.

Comment: You only have one panel though? I think Paul and I are saying the same thing I just went into detail a bit more. Of course you draw directly onto the panel, but you'll need a frame to add the panel to, and then draw all your images onto that panel directly.

Answer (score 0):

We all had that what you have once ;-)

First of all, never use Null layout because then you make sizes static and your application will not work on other resolutions like desired.

Best layoutmanager to use: GridBagLayout !

Why ? very flexible and you can get all components exactly on the place you want, discarding the resolution. Its harder to set up but better result eventually.